# Nexus 4 not getting connected to PC

Tags: usb-connection-mode, nexus-4

Some days back, My nexus was getting connected to the computer. But yesterday I discovered, it is no more like that. It is only getting charged via USB connection. No notification of connection received, either on phone or computer. what to do? Kindly suggest !

Comment: Have you checked *Settings->Connections->USB connection type*? Maybe you accidentally mis-configured it (which can happen easily, as sometimes it pops up a selection box when you connect your device).

Answer (score 11):

go to settings << storage << choose option at upper right corner << USB computer connection << enable Media Device option .

Comment: What Android are you referring to? Care to post a screenshot for guidance for OP? :)

Comment: @Aditya refres to android versions 4.2 and above I suppose. In nexus 4, after enabling the developer options by tapping 7 times on the Build Number ( Setting >> About Phone >> Build Number) the device wont be connected in a media storage mode unless we enable MTP option in Settings >> Storage >> Menu >> Media Device

Answer (score 2):

### Transfer files through USB (Windows & Mac OS)

You can use a USB cable to transfer music, pictures, and other files from your device to a computer and vice versa.

---

### **Related settings**

To change your device's USB connection options, touch **Settings > Device > Storage > Menu > USB computer connection**.

---

### **Windows transfer**

1. Connect your device to the USB port on your computer. Its USB storage is mounted as a
   drive and appears on your computer screen.
2. Copy files back and forth as you would using any other external device.
3. When you finish, eject the device from within Windows before unplugging the USB cable.

---

### **Mac OS transfer**

1. Install Android File Transfer from www.android.com/filetransfer, and
   follow the instructions there. (If you are using Android File
   Transfer for the first time, double-click it to open it. After the
   first connection, it opens automatically whenever you connect.)
2. Connect your device to your computer with a USB cable. Android File
   Transfer starts, if it’s not already running, and opens a window
   that displays the contents of your device, along with storage space
   details at the bottom of the window.
3. Work with this window much as you do in the Finder window: open and
   close folders, create new folders, and drag files to or from it and
   other Finder windows.
4. Disconnect the USB cable when you finish.

**By Google site: [Device settings](https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/2840804?hl=en)**

Answer (score 0):

For those who are getting problems with adb, you can do this:

1. Go to device manager
2. If there is is something called android device at the top or at the second dropdown, uninstall it
3. Download the drivers and install

Answer (score -1):

Try a different USB port or cable.